# Python - selenium. Не получается аплоуднуть изображение в input[type='file']

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, автоматизация, pytest

На странице используется фреймворк vuesax:
https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/upload.html#default

При выполнении функции `self.element_is_visible(self.locators.UPL_FILE).send_keys(rf"C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\Project\files\jpeg.jpeg")`
где UPL_FILE:

```
UPL_FILE = (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "input[type='file']")
```

Уходит в таймаут, ощущение что он не видит инпута.

На https://demoqa.com/upload-download данная функция срабатывает.

Подскажите, может переключиться на фрейм, или есть другие варианты грузануть изображение в инпут?

Фото:

1. https://prnt.sc/UZ_X5TP9HuUH
2. https://prnt.sc/SYq3XWP28kHY

Answer (score 1):

Да, вы правильно заметили, что `input` не реагирует на click(). Так делают когда хотят привязать событие через JavaScript к `input`, но чтоб для пользователя он выглядел стандартно. Поэтому клик привязали к родительскому `div`, это видно в отладчике хром. Из-за нестандартной работы `input`, мы не можем передать строку с путем к файлу через `.send_keys`, пришлось использовать библиотеку для управления клавиатурой `keyboard`. С `PyAutoGUI` под виндоус 10 у меня не получилось.

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

import keyboard


url = 'https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/upload.html#default'

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)

try:
    # Ждем пока элемент станет кликабельным или выбрасываем исключение по времени.
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div[class='con-input-upload']")))
    element.click()
    # Ждем пока откроется окно с выбором файла.
    time.sleep(10)
    # Заполняем поле ввода пути и жмем на Enter.
    keyboard.write(r"C:\Users\ф\Desktop\Лазурная схема.jpg")
    keyboard.press('enter')

    # Дальше вам надо найти кнопку "загрузить файл" и кликнуть по ней.
    
finally:
    time.sleep(5)
    driver.quit()
```

Дальше дело за вами, если будут трудности создавайте новый вопрос.

p.s. Мои выводы о работе данного блока не верные, более "чистое" решение в другом ответе Steenkle.

Comment: Сергей здравствуйте! Это я задавал вопрос, про Ваш метод в курсе, костыль называем)
И так... Убил я на это три дня, вместе с коллегами решили вопрос с помощью driver.execute_script.
Смотрите ответ, выше оставлю, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

В итоге мешал `opacity`, селениум не видит инпута, пришлось посовокупляться пару дней))

```
driver.execute_script("for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))) {value.setAttribute('style', 'opacity: 1') }")
```

В итоге скрипт присваивает `opacity` значение 1, тем самым получаем чистый инпут:
https://prnt.sc/pym3lJIMkbMw

в который сработает send_keys, и можно будет аплоуднуть документ. Всем спасибо за внимание)

Полный код:

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

def disable_opacity():
    """ disable all opacity in input[type='file'] """
    return driver.execute_script("for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))) { value.setAttribute('style', 'opacity: 1') }")

def upl_file():
    file = rf'C:\Users\user\PycharmProjects\project\example.jpeg'
    upl_btn = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//input[@type='file']")
    upl_btn.send_keys(file)


url = 'https://lusaxweb.github.io/vuesax/components/upload.html#default'
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
driver.get(url)
disable_opacity()
time.sleep(2)  # Видим что появилась кнопка
upl_file()
time.sleep(5)  # Видим что изображение загрузилось
driver.quit()




if __name__ == '__main__':
    pass
```

Comment: input, так у меня и не срабатывает после добавления вашей строки. Добавьте, пожалуйста, полный работающий код.

Comment: Скрипт 
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(document.getElementsByTagName('input'))) { value.setAttribute('style', 'opacity: 1') }
Полностью отключает все opacity на странице, тем самым в одном кейсе достаточно ввести 1 раз функцию после попадания на страницу, и дальше работать с изображениями/файлами.

Comment: Да, все работает, снимаю перед вами шляпу!